# Lists: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, list

I need help with this code, I get an error message that says

```
File "<tmp 6>", line 4, in <module>
n.append(names)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

**Code:**

```
names = ['','','','','']   
for i in range(1,6):    
    n = input("Enter a name: ")   
    n.append(names)          
print (names)
```

Comment: You should append the value `n` to the list `names`, i. e. `names.appned(n)`; but you did the opposite. Plus, if you want to get 5 names from user, you shouldn't initialize your list; you just define an empty list like this: `names = []`. Otherwise you'll have a list containing 5 empty strings and 5 other strings obtained from user.

Comment: May be more helpful tutorial: [AttributeError: ‘str’ object has no attribute ‘append’](https://devnote.in/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-append/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're trying to append the string `n` to the list `names`, you got the syntax backwards.

```
names.append(n)
```

You should also probably indent it so it's inside the loop:

```
for i in range(1,6):    
    n = input("Enter a name: ")   
    names.append(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to append to your input String n the list names where the string should be added. It should be the opposite.

```
names = ['','','','','']   
for i in range(1,6):    
    n = input("Enter a name: ")   
names.append(n)          
print (names)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!